# Implementing Javascript Video like Youtube Editor

Tags: javascript, youtube, html5-video

I've been searching how to implement a web application which provide the functionality to edit videos. just like the [youtube Editor](https://www.youtube.com/editor). What are best and free libraries out there for building a web app like this?. A library which support react would be great!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the one you are looking for [html5-videoEditor](https://github.com/casatt/html5-videoEditor). This is more of a proof of concept than a fully functional web-application. Right now it allows you to load videos into the browser, they get automatically uploaded via WebsSocket to a node.js application, where those assets get transcoded (H264/WebM/OGG). Then you can create a composition (=new video), copy videos to the stage, trim them, transform them, stack them and then finally encode them on the server-side using AviSynth and ffmpeg Currently each encoding job will produce a H264 encoded video.